# Understanding how to apply a slicer to a percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am after a way in Power BI to output four numbers divided using Visual level filters which represent Orders as well as a percentage of that Order against the total Orders.

This works fine until I begin to apply a report level slicer and the data becomes a proportion of the total orders for a specific store.

Is there a way I can display the percentages as a total of the newly filtered numbers once I apply the slicer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ALLSELECTED` function.

For example, if you have a measure called `[SumSales]` you can get the sum of sales divided by the total of all the items selected in the Slicer (visual filter).

```
Ratio := [SumSales] / CALCULATE( [SumSales], ALLSELECTED(ColumnInSlicer))
```

Comment: Hi Orlando. Thanks for the reply.

I have looked into ALLSELECTED before but could not get it to give me my answer.

The new column created gives me a total of 1 or 100% in each row.

Comment: What's the layout of you pivot? 
In other words, what do you have in the Values area, Rows area and in the visual filter?

Comment: Not using a pivot, but rather PowerBI.

Field is Sum of Column, filtered by Difference in time.

Column = Query5[Orders]/CALCULATE([SUMORDERS],ALLSELECTED(Query5))